# What is the meaning of "a not-so-subtle-dig"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Would somebody clarify the meaning of "a not-so-subtle dig" in this text?

> "Super UHD TV" is of course a not-so-subtle dig at Samsung’s "SUHD TV"

And in context with the paragraph where it orginated:

> Jumping to LCDs, LG has chosen to name its high-end models “Super UHD TVs”. This is of course a not-so-subtle dig at Samsung who has chosen “SUHD” as the marketing name for its high-end LCDs. So what does “Super UHD TV” entail exactly? LG says that it a moniker for 4K LCD combined with quantum dot technology. The latter is used to expand the color gamut for better colors. The three UH95, UH85 and UH77 models all support Dolby Vision and HDR10. LG’s new high-end LCDs are not “UHD Premium” certified like Samsung’s new high-end LCD but they hope that customers will value Dolby Vision more.

Comment: dig: [a criticism or insult that is directed toward a particular person or group](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dig)  subtle: [hard to notice or see : not obvious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtle)  In other words, a criticism or insult that is not too hard to notice and is obvious.

Comment: Do you have a source for the full quote? It's rather long and awkward to fit into a question, and it reads almost like subtle advertising. It would be preferable to link to that and just keep the line you are asking about in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **dig** is a "[a criticism or insult that is directed toward a particular person or group](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dig)."

**Subtle** means "[hard to notice or see; not obvious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtle)."

So this is "a criticism or insult" that is "not very hard to notice" or "is obvious".  This phrase uses understatement to soften the effect a little - saying "an insult that is hard to miss" is more direct and stronger than "a not-too-subtle dig".  The phrase *a not-too-subtle dig* is a common one.  Some examples:

> [...said Walmart in a news release, in a not-too-subtle dig at Amazon.](http://pix11.com/2016/07/11/amazon-prime-day-set-for-3-a-m-tuesday-walmart-counters-with-all-week-deals/)
>
> [The first part of the quotation contains a not-too-subtle dig at A.P. Watt.](https://books.google.com/books?id=tG9B6b5jFZgC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22not+too+subtle+dig%22&source=bl&ots=BhxWZ8GJbj&sig=wos2-uJvLKY6-q42yjdHogdSssg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwialOXguf3OAhWCJh4KHRxuBhQQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=%22not%20too%20subtle%20dig%22&f=false)
>
> [It was a not-too-subtle dig at Mrs. Beaufort, but no one seemed to connect the remark to her.](https://books.google.com/books?id=baQ_Pb5uQzMC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=%22not+too+subtle+dig%22&source=bl&ots=-rVenumsrQ&sig=ue8ULM6dDFjkPJjv9iDVex8XfKk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwialOXguf3OAhWCJh4KHRxuBhQQ6AEIQjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22not%20too%20subtle%20dig%22&f=false)